# Should I use 403, 404 or 444 to block an API end point in nginx level

Tags: security, nginx

I would like to block some API end point in nginx level. I use

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /app/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /app/key.pem;

    location = /this_api_path_should_be_blocked {
        return 444;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I was wondering, for security best practice, what is the good error code to be returned. Should it be

- 403 Forbidden Error
- 404 Not Found Error
- 444 Connection Closed Without Response

Comment: I don't think the status code will affect the security at all. This is up to you which code to return - design it as you think what makes sense and then describe it in the documentation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a status code that best matches the behaviour of your API, at the end the returned code/message is for having a better understanding of what happened, nothing that may affect the security of the API itself.

In your example, if the path is blocked probably you could add some allow/deny policies by using the [nginx access module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) and this by will return `403 Forbidden` by default.

If you would like to return a custom `444` you could do something like this:

```
location = /this_api_path_should_be_blocked {
    allow 10.0.0.0/16;
    deny all;
    error_page 403 =444 /444.html;
}
```

If is a path that requires some authorization you could stick to the status code in this case`403 Forbidden` would make sense, even some API's return 404 like Github, for example https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Answer (score 1):

**Whichever is appropriate to the action**

If your trying to block `/this_api_path_should_be_blocked` from *unauthorised* calls, then you should return the **403: Forbidden** because this informs the user that the path exists, and that they just aren't aren't allowed to access it. Should they be logged in? Should they have a token to go with it to prove they are an authorized user?

If the user makes a call to a path that simply does not exist, it should return a **404: Not Found** response. This should be the default response to *all* calls that are not defined.

Comment: If you are blocking access because the request is unauthorised (ie login has failed) then 401 Unauthorised should be your initial response, accompanied by a WWW-Authenticate header to explain how to authenticate. If the user has authenticated correctly but doesnt have permission to access the resource then its 403 forbidden

Comment: I'm not sure if you're mixing up authorization and authentication. But in this example, the 403 is being provided because the user is not authenticated (they lack an API key or something). If the user *is* authenticated but they are not authorized to access that resource,  they should be provided a 401. This example does not account for authenticated but unauthorized users. Hope this clears things up

Comment: It's confusing because the word "Unauthorized" is a bad choice. If you stick rigidly to the standards then 401 is the correct response for both cases. A 401 response must include a WWW-Authenticate header containing an authentication challenge. In reality the standard is confusing for users who receive a 401, then authenticate but are unauthorised and receive another 401, so many servers serve a 403 to authenticated but unauthorised users. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-3.1 https://httpstatuses.com/401 and https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8